# IE browser automation with excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to automate browser tasks using excel vba. Need to hit some urls for testing purpose. I tried to hit each URLs in a Loop But everytime IE browser opens in same session.

I am trying to automate browser tasks using excel vba. Need to hit some urls for testing purpose. I tried to hit each URLs in a Loop But everytime IE browser opens in same session. Please help to modify code to open close ie session each time and open in a new session eveytime.

```
Sub test()
    ' open IE, navigate to the desired page and loop until fully loaded
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    my_url = "*****UL*******"

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate my_url
    End With

    Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("0:00:10"))

    Application.SendKeys "Username"
    Application.SendKeys "{TAB}"

    Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("0:00:10"))

    Application.SendKeys "Password"    
    Application.SendKeys "{TAB}"
    Application.SendKeys "{RETURN}"

    Do Until Not IE.Busy And IE.readyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

    Set IE = Nothing
End Sub
```

Execting IE bowse to open in a new session each time. Please help to modify code

Comment: Can you show the loop you created? I think you create the IE object outside the loop.

Comment: What do you mean by "new session"?

Comment: @alex de jong,  even without the loop when i run this code for the second time with other url it is loading the same previous url which i used previously. Please help to modify code to open ie new session everytime so that it will not hit the same url everytime it is loading

Comment: So if you debug through the code, will it pass `.Navigate my_url`? And is `my_url` your new url or the previous one in that case? It would be strange if that line of code shows the right url but IE still navigates to an old url.

Comment: Don't set IE = Nothing. That discards the session. Also, if you have a loop, keep it within the same Sub. When the Sub ends, all of the local variables are discarded, which would include IE.